# Creating list with specified a length and combining other lists

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a list that combines elements of two other lists, one is a value and one is not.

I've tried having two separate lists with and using the join function and append function to combine the two elements together at the certain stage.
To match the length of list d to list a I've used a while loop as a counter.

```
a=7*[1]

b=[1,2,3,4,5]

c=['a','b','c']

d=[]
```

The outcome i'm trying to achieve is such that: 
list d becomes the length of list a
& is a combination of list b and list c

```
d=[1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,2c,3a]
```

Comment: You've described your code in vague terms, why not actually post it?

Comment: how can you combine different types of elements? One is int and other is string. Also, there may be different lists based upon combination of same length. Try specifying in detail of what you want.

Comment: What if `a` is of length 50 !?

Answer (score 0):

Can think of a Naive solution for now

```
def create(bk, ck, len_required):
    dk = []
    for bitem in bk:
        for citem in ck:
            dk.append(str(bitem) + citem)
            if len(dk) == len_required:
                return dk


len_required = len(a)
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
d = create(b, c, len_required)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [str(b[int(i / len(c)) % len(b)]) + str(c[i % len(c)]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

This iterates i from 0 to len(a) and concatenates b[int(i / len(c)) % len(b)] and c[i % len(c)] in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a list comprehension:

```
d = [str(v)+L for v in b*len(a) for L in c][:len(a)]
```

or, if you're allowed to use itertools:

```
from itertools import cycle

cycleA = cycle(str(v)+L for v in b for L in c)
d = [ next(cycleA) for _ in a ]
```